# delete string for each line with sed

Tags: sed

My file contains x number of lines, I would like to remove the string before and after the reference string at the beginning and end of each line.
The reference string and string to remove are separated by space.

The file contains :

```
test.user.passs
test.user.location
global.user
test.user.tel
global.pass
test.user.email string_err
@ttt...> test.user.car ->  
test.user.address
è_ 788 test.user.housse
test.user.child
{kl78>&é} global.email
global.foo
test.user.foo
```

How to remove the string at the start of each line which contain "test" string and also the end of each line separated by space or tab with `sed`?

The desired result is :

```
test.user.passs
test.user.location
global.user
test.user.tel
global.pass
test.user.email
test.user.car 
test.user.address
test.user.housse
test.user.child
{kl78>&é} global.email
global.foo
test.user.foo
```

Comment: Which language do you want a solution in?

Comment: with sed is better I think

Comment: very unclear, explain a bit more with used data (comment in expected result ?) what is reference string in this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your question as: find the first word that is "word characters and at least one dots"

Tcl:

```
echo '
set fh [open [lindex $argv 1] r]
while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {puts [regexp -inline {\w+(?:\.\w+)+} $line]}
' | tclsh - file
```

sed

```
sed -r 's/.*\<([[:alpha:]]+(\.[[:alpha:]]+)).*/\1/' file
```

perl

```
perl -nE '/(\w+(\.\w+)+)/ and say $1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

using sed like

```
sed -r 's/^[^ ]+[ ]+([^ ]+)[ ]+[^ ]*/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.*(test\S+).*/\1/' file
```